# Overlapping with CABasicAnimation Scaling

Tags: swift, animation

I have a collection view where the first cell needs to be animated with scaling. The standard cabasic animation's behaviour goes under neighbouring cell but I need to find a way so the scaling animation overlaps neighbouring cell. I've tried to put a clear view on a cell and animate it, so it would've been at the top of view hierarchy but it didn't help. Is there any assumptions how it can be achieved?

```
class func pulse(view: UIView, sizeMultiplier: Float, duration: TimeInterval, repeatCount: Float = 1.0) {
    let pulseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    pulseAnimation.duration = duration
    pulseAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(value: sizeMultiplier)
    pulseAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
    pulseAnimation.autoreverses = true
    pulseAnimation.repeatCount = repeatCount
    view.layer.add(pulseAnimation, forKey: nil)
    
}
```

Comment: Show your code, please.

Comment: @matt I've just added the snippet

Comment: So you don't increase the layer's `zPosition`?

Comment: @matt so, exactly the layer's zPosition needs to be increased? Didn't think of it...

Comment: @matt I've just changed the layer's zIndex, the animation still goes under, unfortunately.

Comment: @matt I apologise, just made it out, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem, feel free to answer your own question if you like.